# How to persist stacked screens when switching between tabs in React Native Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-tabnavigator

I am using a bottom tab navigator created with `createBottomTabNavigator()` and passing it several screens, each of which contain their own stack navigation:

```
const tabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    TradingStack,
    LendingStack,
    FinanceStack,
    AccountBalancesStack,
    OtherStack,
  },
  {
    tabBarComponent: props => (
      <NavigationFooter />
    )
  }
);
```

I am passing it my own custom bottom navigator component called `<NavigationFooter />`. When `tabBarComponent` is omitted, a built-in bottom tab navigator is used, however I need more functionality than this built-in solution offers. The issue is, when using my custom tab bar, I lose stack persistence in the individual screens. To clarify, let's say my `TradingStack` screen has several screens that stack on top of it, and I open one of those. When using the default tab bar, if I switch to the `LendingStack` screen and then back to `TradingStack`, I will still be on the stacked screen that was pushed on top of the root `TradingStack` screen.

However, when using my custom tab bar component, moving between these tabs/screens will always bring me to the root of each one instead of bringing me back to the stacked screen that the tab was on before switching away from it. Here's my custom Footer component:

```
function Footer({navigation}) {
  return(
    <View style={styles.tabBarStyle}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.tabStyle} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Trading')} />
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.tabStyle} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Lending')} />
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.tabStyle} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Finance')} />
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.tabStyle} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('AccountBalances')} />
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.tabStyle} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('TabScreen')} />
    </View>
  );
}

const NavigationFooter = withNavigation(Footer);
```

As you can see, when one of the `TouchableOpacity` elements is pressed, I use `navigation.navigate()` to go to the desired screen, but, as mentioned, this brings me to the root of the screen. I understand that this is basically explicitly telling the app to navigate to a root screen of a tab, but I don't know how to make the tab "remember" the stacked screen it was on before I move away, as is the behavior of the default tab bar.

Comment: Could it be the way you're using your custom bottom navigation component: Maybe you should directly use the `navigation` provided by the bottom navigation bar instead of the `withNavigation` HOC?
`tabBarComponent: props => <NavigationFooter {...props} /> // ℹ️ pass it here`

Comment: I changed it so that `navigation` is passed here, however the behavior is still the same as described in the original question. Still, this is better than using the `withNavigation` HOC, so thank you for this suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the name of the actual stack to `navigation.navigate` instead of the name of the starting screen on that specific tab, and the stacked screens should persist. So, instead of, for example

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.tabStyle} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Trading')}/> //name of the screen
```

you should pass it

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.tabStyle} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('TradingStack')}/> //name of the stack
```

assuming `Trading` is the starting screen within the `TradingStack`.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly. You must be a master hacker or something, Mr. Zlatan.

Comment: @LiteralMetaphore you can call me Mr. Robot ;)